# Ubuntu 15.04 not working with Broadcom B4311

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom, 15.04

I've installed a fresh copy of Xubuntu 15.04 and I can't get my Broadband B4311 Wifi card working.
I had Ubuntu GNOME 14.04, and I solved the problem using the b43 driver, so I'd already done a lot of tweaking, now neither the b43 driver or the Broadcom proprietary driver works.
Is this kernel related? Has anyone had the same problem?

Comment: Can you add the result of `ls /etc/modprobe.d/ | grep bcm43` and `lspci -nnk | grep 280`

Comment: - alsa-base.conf                    blacklist.conf              blacklist-modem.conf         blacklist-watchdog.conf  intel-microcode-blacklist.conf  vmwgfx-fbdev.conf
blacklist-ath_pci.conf            blacklist-firewire.conf     blacklist-oss.conf           dkms.conf                iwlwifi.conf
blacklist-broadcom-wireless.conf  blacklist-framebuffer.conf  blacklist-rare-network.conf  fbdev-blacklist.conf     mlx4.conf

Comment: - 00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge [8086:2448] (rev e2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation 82801GBM (ICH7-M) LPC Interface Bridge [8086:27b9] (rev 02)
00:1f.1 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller [8086:27df] (rev 02)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 82801GBM/GHM (ICH7-M Family) SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:27c5] (rev 02)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)

Comment: 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM4311 802.11b/g Wireless ... [103c:1364]
 Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
 Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
 Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
 Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
 Region 0: Memory at d6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge

Comment: So what is in the blacklist file `cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-broadcom-wireless.conf`

Comment: wl driver that was the default after install

Comment: Have you installed the firmware? `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer` and rebooted?

Comment: yes, i've installed and rebooted

Comment: Anything in `rfkill list all`

Comment: I've just edit blacklist-broadcom-wireless.conf and the b43 driver was blacklisted, i guess i was very sleepy last night, i just remove it and runned sudo update-initramfs -u and it's done. Thank you very much. Now i feel bad for starting this

Comment: As long as it works now

Comment: Thank you, my ethernet cable is out and i'm on wireless again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
sudo -H gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-broadcom-wireless.conf
```

removed the line with `b43`

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Details found [here on the help.ubuntu.com wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx?action=show&redirect=BroadcomSTA%28Wireless%29)

Answer (score 2):

Correction:

Actually, the correct file to edit on gedit is `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf` since this file is for the Broadcom 43xx series wifi chipsets. Don't forget to reboot the PC once these changes are made to take into effect.

So to put it into steps (for some people who don't get what I'm talking about):

Open Terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Type

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf
```

Comment out (by putting a `#` at the start of the line) any items with the words `bcm43` or `bcm43xxx` in them. Save the file and close gedit once you're done with these changes.

Reboot the PC.

**NOTE**: some PCs may require you to activate the wifi card through either a combo key press (FN + F# or an unknown side/front switch) before you can see your wifi networks on the Network Connections.